# Connect to yahoo mail using IMAP in php

Tags: php, imap

I'm using a library to connect to mail servers using IMAP .
I can connect to gmail and my server easily but when I want to connect to yahoo I get following error

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PhpImap\ConnectionException' with message 'IMAP method imap_open() failed with error: Can't connect to internal.imap.mail.g03.yahoodns.net,993: Connection refused. Can't connect to internal.imap.mail.g03.yahoodns.net,993: Connection refused'

and this is my code

```
$mailbox = new PhpImap\Mailbox('{imap.mail.yahoo.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX', 'email', 'pass', __DIR__);
$mailsIds = $mailbox->searchMailbox('ALL');
if(!$mailsIds) {
    die('Mailbox is empty');
}
$mail = $mailbox->getMail($mailsIds[0]);
print_r($mail);
echo "\n\nAttachments:\n";
print_r($mail->getAttachments());
```

what's wrong?

thanks

Comment: `Connection refused` says that the server you are sending your request to does not accept the connection. Make sure you have the right server name and port